# Django upload to Amazon S3 via signed urls: wrong content type

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

In my Django application (RESTful API with DjangoRestFramwework), I have to store images on Amazon S3. Due to some technical constraints, we have to use direct upload by a client application using signed URLs. Everything works fine but after the upload is performed by the client, the content type is always set to `binary/octet-stream`, while I naturally want it to be, say, `image/jpeg`. As it is mentioned in the Amazon S3 documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html), response-content-type header has to be added to the signed URL in order to ensure the Content-Type of the response by S3 will be correct. Here is my code for signing the URL (written according to `boto` documentation):

```
connection = S3Connection(
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)    
url = connection.generate_url(
    100,
    'PUT',
    settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
    some_key,
    response_headers={'response-content-type':'image/jpeg'},
)
```

This code works almost fine: it generates a URL which I then successfully use for upload. The `curl` request is:

```
curl -v --request PUT --upload-file ~/file.jpg --header "response-content-type : image/jpeg" "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.jpg?Signature=ytmFHV13qeVg1aU6xyTuysOG4Bs%3D&Expires=1440263232&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response-content-type=image/jpeg"
```

Unfortunately, when I access the file, the content type is still wrong (`binary/octet-stream`). Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, after a lot of experiments I found an answer. I was inspired by... [official Amazon S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) :) Here is the URL signing code:

```
url = connection.generate_url(
    100,
    'PUT',
    settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
    some_key,
    headers = {'x-amz-acl' : 'public-read', 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}
)
```

The principal change here is the headers section, where I put `'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'` (`'x-amz-acl' : 'public-read'` is also useful since it makes your file publicly available for reading). Then you have to place `Content-Type` header to your HTTP request. In my case, I used `curl` as follows:

```
curl -v --request PUT --upload-file ~/file.jpg  --header "Content-Type: image/jpeg" your_signed_url
```

Enjoy!

Comment: is there a way to use this with django-storages?

Comment: @DataGreed I am not sure, I understand what you mean, but I can tell you that boto works with django-storages and I use the latter in my application to redirect default file storage to Amazon S3